# Is there a 1:1 mapping between static typing and static dispatch vs dynamic typing and dynamic dispatch?

Tags: julia, dynamic-typing, dynamic-dispatch, multiple-dispatch

**Context:** I'm learning Julia and trying to figure out multiple dispatch. I understand the conceptual leap from single dynamic dispatch to multiple dynamic dispatch, but I'm trying to pin down single dynamic dispatch.

**Question:** Is the following 1:1 mapping true:

- In every language that has dynamic typing, there is dynamic dispatch
- In every language that has static typing, there is static dispatch

I can't think of a situation in which you'd want

- Static typing with dynamic dispatch (because the variables won't be dynamic, so why have dynamic dispatch?)
- The opposite situation: dynamic typing with static dispatch (if a variable changes type, wouldn't you want the function to be called on the run time type?).

Comment: Would static typing include union types such as Union{Int64, Float64}?

Comment: You can totally have static typing with dynamic dispatch, that's the whole point of Virtual Table in C/C++/C#, and `Go`'s generics are implemented as dynamic dispatch IIRC.

And even though Julia is a dynamic typing language, static dispatch happens all the time as an optimization because JIT compiler can figure out which methods you're calling thus avoiding dynamic dispatch